# Simplifying Nested Conditionals using Logical Operators: Logical Operators are not working?

Tags: python, nested, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm new to coding and am only in the third week of my CS course. I'm working on an assignment where we have to create a nested conditional and then simplify it into a single conditional using logical operators. I believed that I had done it correctly but my simplified conditional will only choose the first option even when the output is less than the given amount.

**Nested conditional:**

```
def steps(s):
   return .04*s
#the average amount of calories burned per step is .04 
walk = steps(6000)
#The variable walk is used to show that my walk was 6,000 steps
hike = steps(7000)
tdee = 1300
#tdee is your Total Daily Energy Expenditure.
day = (tdee + walk + hike)
#this if else statemnet is going to decide of you have burned the recomended number of calories 
for the entire day
if day > 2000:
   print("Success!")
else:
   if day > 1700:
       print("Almost!")
   else:
       if day > 1500:
           print("Try again.")
       else:
           print("Failure.")
```

**Simplified Single Conditional:**

```
def steps(s):
   return .04*s
#the average amount of calories burned per step is .04
walk = steps(500)
#The variable walk is used to show that my walk was 6,000 steps
hike = steps(7000)
tdee = 1300
#tdee is your Total Daily Energy Expenditure.
day = (tdee + walk)
#this if else statement is going to decide if you have burned the recommended number of calories 
for the entire day
if day >= 2000 or >= 1700:
    print("You are within the recommended calorie range.")
else:
    print("You are under the recommended calorie range. Try again.")
```

With the values given it should give the response that you are 'under' the recommended amount but it does not. (It may also be important to note that I am using python anywhere.)

Comment: The second example is not valid syntax. Also they contain different messages to be `print`ed, so how are they supposed to give the same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming it's just a copy/paste issue bringing it to StackOverflow, but if not, then you need to add a `#` to your `for the entire day` line.

For your question though, it's important to understand a couple things. Firstly, your `if day >= 2000 or >= 1700` has two issues: First, that it would need to be `if day >= 2000 or day >= 1700` to not crash. Python's logical `and`, `or`, etc. connect two statements, and `>= 1700` by itself isn't a statement - it needs a left-hand side. You can picture chained conditionals as if they were encased in parentheses, like `if (day >= 2000) or (>= 1700)`, which shows more clearly why you need to repeat `day` after your `or`. The second important thing here is that that statement is redundant: if `day >= 2000` is true, `day >= 1700` would've been true too. With that in mind, you can simplify that down to just `if day >= 1700:` and have an equivalent statement.

Your question also has another gotcha: you say it doesn't trigger the "enough calories" case even when it should, but your `walk`-based `day` value is only 1320, which isn't enough to trigger it. For that matter, your `hike`-based `day` value is only 1580, which is also below 1700. I'm not sure if the value of `0.04*s` is the right value, or if 7000 steps is too low, but either way, no combination of these things makes a `day` that would trigger `>=1700`